# Rotational kinematics problem @ $\theta = 0$

Tags: nonlinear-equations, numerical-modelling

I'm simulating a magnetic dipole that is subjected to an evolving magnetic field.  In ISO convention ($\theta$ is the polar angle and $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle), my equation of motion that is giving me issues is

$$\ddot\phi = \frac{\textrm{garbage}}{\sin{\theta}}.$$

So this equation makes perfect sense, as $\theta$ goes to one of the two poles, $0$ or $\pi$, then the azimuthal angle has to quickly change (if $\theta$ went directly through the pole then $\phi$ would change almost instantly to be $\phi_0 \pm \pi$)  My question is not understanding what is going on; rather, how is the best way to approach this problem since $\ddot\phi$ blows up and the simulation stops at the poles?

So far I have tried moving my coordinate system so the poles were in a place where possibly the trajectory wouldn't pass through it then convert my coordinates back (this worked but occasionally I do get a trajectory close and it blows up).  I've tried decreasing step size, which makes it better, but still if you get too close it blows up.  I've tried looking on-line since I'm sure I'm not the first to come across this problem, but was unable to find anything.  Any help would be great!

Comment: what type of discretization are you using - finite differences (you'll likely need some special treatment to avoid that _pole problem_, see [here](http://kiwi.atmos.colostate.edu/group/dave/at604pdf/Chapter_12.pdf)) or finite elements (better equipped to handle this), or something else?

Comment: If you're doing a discrete-element-like simulation where an external field acts on a collection of bodies (which may also interact), I recommend that you encode your body orientations using unit quaternions. They are well-suited to representing rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and they avoid many issues that plague other orientation representations (see wiki). This allows the rest of your code to use Cartesian coordinates, and everything pretty much works out. This is the approach commonly adopted in rigid body dynamics codes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Comment: @TylerOlsen Sorry, I meant to say thank you for the link to the wiki page.  It was exactly what I was after.